# Unselect hidden mesh after unhide

Tags: python, modeling, selection-tools

Is it possible to unselect only the parts that were hidden, after the unhide command (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)? I want to keep the previous selection.

[image]

[image: sdf]

Comment: While it's not python solution, you can use vertex group for that. Create one, assign selected vertices to it, unhide and deselect everythiing. Then, select vertices assigned to the group.

Comment: I did python solution which unhides all verts/faces and leave selection as it was before. http://pastebin.com/H4gzFYEr
But i don't know how to add it to shortcut and to the addon.

Answer (score 10):

There may be a more elegant solution, but i believe this process gives you the result you are seeking.

Select the mesh vertices you are interested in.
Invert your selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>).
Unhide the hidden mesh components (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>).
Invert your selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> again.

Comment: very nice work around. UVed

Answer (score 4):

Here is an addon I made a couple years ago which makes this functionality appear in the toolbox as `Reveal Hidden, deselected`, updated for Blender 2.80:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Reveal Hidden, deselected",
    "description": "Unhide/Reveal hidden geometry without it getting added to selection.",
    "author": "Zyl",
    "version": (1, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "Toolbox > Reveal Hidden, deselected",
    "category": "Mesh"
}

import bpy
import bmesh

class RevealHiddenDeselected(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Unhide/Reveal hidden geometry without it getting added to selection."""
    bl_idname = "mesh.reveal_hidden_deselected"
    bl_label = "Reveal Hidden, deselected"
    bl_options = { 'REGISTER', 'UNDO' }

    def execute(self, context):
        me = context.active_object.data
        if me is None:
            return { 'FINISHED' }
        bm = None
        inedit = me.is_editmode
        if not inedit:
            print("Must be in edit mode to unhide w/o selecting.")
            return { 'FINISHED' }
        else:
            bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
        if bm is None:
            return { 'FINISHED' }
        for v in bm.verts:
            v.hide_set(False)
        for e in bm.edges:
            e.hide_set(False)
        for f in bm.faces:
            f.hide_set(False)
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, False, False)
        return { 'FINISHED' }

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(RevealHiddenDeselected)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RevealHiddenDeselected)
```

Comment: Tested, works great. Thanks for sharing. Could it be possible to provide a link to th 2.79 version?

Comment: Try this for pre-2.80: https://pastebin.com/ycPwcWs4

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Uncheck *Select* in your Keymap preferences. It'll work for *Object Mode*, *Edit Mode* and much more.