# how to unhide all objects with only active object selected

Tags: modeling

in object mode, you can toggle the visibility of active object with ( object - show/hide - hide unselected ) and (object - show/hide - show hidden objects) , but with the operator " show hidden objects" it selects all of the objects in a collection, is there a way to show all, but not select everything, only the active object?

Comment: Duplicate of [Unselect hidden mesh after unhide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32150/unselect-hidden-mesh-after-unhide)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the post you linked is for edit mode, this one is for object mode.